# List has no attribute 'keys' when writing to CSV in Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I am making a Python Script which fetches JSON from an endpoint and then writes it to a CSV, however I keep getting this error when trying to write a specific key. What should I do?

[My code and the error I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cVjC.png)

[What JSON data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB8FP.png)

[What I am aiming to have in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qynQV.png)

Comment: Please add a text version of your error message to the question.

Comment: Excpetion has occured: AttributeError
'List' object has no attribute 'keys'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Results" is of type `list` and not `dict`.
Therefore, you can't treat it like a dictionary and invoke keys()

I guess what you want to do is remove the '[' ']' from "Results" in your json file

Comment: Apologies if I am doing something wrong, I have tried the following and get the same exception
---
for driverId in resultstring['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races']["Results"]:
    write.writerow(driverId.keys())
    csv_file.close()

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add the whole code and json file?

Comment: I can't post the JSON here as it is too long to post, however my code is below,  See the question for pic of JSON

from audioop import ratecv
from calendar import c
import json
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen


csv_file=open('csv_format.csv', 'w')

endpoint = "https://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json"
response =  urlopen(endpoint)

resultstring = json.load(response)

write=csv.writer(csv_file)


write.writerow(resultstring[0]['MRData'].keys())



write.writerow(resultstring['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races']['Results'][0].keys())
csv_file.close()

Comment: Based on your JSON file here is what worked for me:  
Option A:  
`for driver_id in results_dict['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Results']:
        print(driver_id.keys())`  
Option B:  
`results_dict['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Results'][0].keys()`

Comment: This works fantastic until the 'driver' key where it will not seperate each key (e.g driverId, nationality) and just put them in one cell. I know why this happens, just not sure how to fix it, if you look at the structure of the JSON it makes sense

Comment: In order to get those keys you'll need to get another level down like this:  
`results_dict['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Results'][0]['Driver'].keys()`

Answer (score 1):

Results is a list of dictionaries. try doing Results[0].keys() instead

Comment: This still gives me the same exception.

Comment: try results[0][drivers].keys()

Comment: I get a KeyError exception which means it cannot find key specificied as far as I am aware.

I have tried with all of the different keys in the JSON data. Still gives KeyError. 

Have been doing - write.writerow(resultstring[0]['MRData'].keys())